# Как отправить сообщение на ответ пользователю Python Disnake

Tags: python, disnake

Как в Disnake реализовать ответ на сообщение. То-есть, если бот отправил какое-то сообщение и если какой-то юзер ответил на него, то бот должен отправить еще одно. Как это сделать? Знаю объясняю плохо но не знаю как еще.

Comment: "ответить" сообщением в чате, или реакцией и тд?

Comment: @ForevorBase сообщением

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я понял как сделать в целом чтобы бот реагировал на упоминания.

```
import disnake

intents = disnake.Intents.all()
client = disnake.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
        await message.channel.send("Пинг!")
```